# How can I centralize a list with css?

Tags: html, css

I have a list and some problems. I can't centralize `< li >`, they are always aligned. Here's an example of how they are:

[image]

Now, as I'm trying to let them:

[image]

Could anyone help me solve this problem please? Here the code I'm using.

HTML

```
<div class="header_middle_menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">E</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">F</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">G</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">H</a></li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

CSS

```
.header_middle_menu{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: 490px;
}

.header_middle_menu li{
    float: left;
}

.header_middle_menu ul{
    list-style: none;
}

.header_middle_menu ul li{
    background: #FB5904;
    display: inline;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 7px;
}

.header_middle_menu ul li a{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.header_middle_menu li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Always good to include a http://jsfiddle.net if you want to get more/better answers to your questions.  I have made one for you here http://jsfiddle.net/n87tG/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do these three things:

- Add `text-align:center;` to `.header_middle_menu`
- Remove `float: left;` from `.header_middle_menu li`
- Change `display: inline;` to `display: inline-block;` in `.header_middle_menu ul li`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/YANGc/)**